# How to write test steps to the generated html report with pytest-html?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I can't find a way to add string to my HTML report that represent my test steps.

I saw in https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html/
that I should try with:

```
extra.text('Add some simple Text')
```

but seems that it doesn't work.

```
from pytest_html import extras

class FirstFeatureTests:

    def setup_class(self):
        print("\n------------ in setup_class ------------")

    def teardown_class(self):
        print("------------ in teardown_class ------------")

    @mark.example
    def test_1_first_feature(self):
        print("starting test !!!!!")
        extras.text("step 1: ")
        extras.text('step 2: ')
        assert True
```

I expect that each test will contains test steps represented as string with iformative description.

is there any way to do so?

Comment: `extras.text()` will not add anything to the report, only prepare the text to be added. You need to use `report.extra.append()` in the custom impl of the `pytest_runtest_makereport` hook, as shown in the example in the docs.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I have another question, How do I pass costum message to the pytest_runtest_makereport hook from the test method?

Comment: I'd probably use the session object, e.g. `def test_spam(request): request.session.foo = 'bar'` and `def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call): foo = item.session.foo`

Answer (score 0):

Allure is certainly better suited for your needs as it has all the test reporting features (steps, feature, stories, etc.) for pytest. But it is written in java and you need to install pytest allure as well as allure binary locally for it to work. And you may have to jump few hoops to make it work in your existing pytest codebase.

If you want to use pytest-html for generating test steps, this is a possible solution:

```
# Contents of top level conftest.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def step(request):
    @pytest.mark.optionalhook
    def pytest_html_results_table_html(request, report, data):
        data.append(html.div(str(request.param), class_='Step'))

#Contents of fixture or test code
def test_a(step):
    step("abc")
    assert True
```

I have not run the code locally but this is what final code for adding step should look like.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to try [allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/) instead of pytest-html in this case. it has easy integration with pytest and the api is really comfortable to use.

check out [this repository](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/) for more information.

and this one for [usage examples](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_pytest).